Why are UPS battery backups all rated in VA instead of AH?
Looking at an online retailer, I see uninterruptible (battery backup) power supplies are marketed as:

"1500VA"
"600VA"
"425VA"
"425VA/260W"
"1500VA/900W"

All measurements of power, a rate at which energy can be delivered.
Whereas most actual batteries themselves are sold as:

"7ah"
"7.2 ah"
"20 Ah"
"12 AH"

i.e. measurements of how much energy they actually store.
Now if I buy a 900 watt UPS and plug a little single board computer in it that draws 5W of power — well, I know I could actually plug 180 such little computers into that UPS I guess. But what I want to know is: if the power goes out on my 900 watt UPS and my computer is drawing 5W, how long will it keep running?
To calculate a runtime I would need to divide the energy available by the power needed to get a duration. So why are all the battery backups marketed only in terms of some "power" rating, instead of disclosing their energy capacity?

This is more of an Electrical Engineering question. You'll probably get better answers faster in a more appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Apart from maximum / continuous power, a UPS's specifications should also include a runtime at a particular load. As every load is different, you should consult the manufacturer's documentation. Some provide a sizing tool/calculator.

Note that a battery is an energy source the provides a DC voltage and up to X Ampere-hours. But the rating on a UPS indicates the maximum (non-reactive) AC power that it can supply to the attached load. Since the power factor of the load is not specified, the actual power consumption (i.e. wattage) of the UPS's load is also unknown.

To calculate the amount of watts the battery can supply over time: Ah x V[olts] / H[ours] = W[atts]  [Ah*V/H=W] e.g. 7Ah*12V/0.25H = 336W (a constant 336W can be supplied for 15min). A 12V 7Ah battery could supply a constant 5W for ~16.8hrs (will be slightly less because the UPS requires power for its electronics during an outage): 7Ah*12V/16.8H = 5W

There are a number of reasons for this, including -

(Especially Lead Acid) battery based UPS's discharge curves are not linear, so there is not always a clear mapping between VA and runtime.   Things like VA vs Watts (power factor), power draw (ie C rate), temperature and age of the batteries can substantially affect runtime, and how far you can run a battery down before damaging it.

The VA rating tells you about the maximum load you can put on the UPS, and this can also be a very loose proxy for the quality of the components - because higher rated UPS's will typically have componentry and cooling which can support higher currents and are thus more robust.

Related to (2) above - very often you can get additional battery packs for a UPS.  This won't affect the VA rating - only the runtime.

Often, the runtime of a UPS is secondary to its power protection abilities - in many use cases the expectation is it needs enough time for a generator to kick in or for you to close out and save your work.  They will also often provide buck and boost so you can continue to work with unstable/out-of-spec power.


I assume you are aware of it but for the sake of completion, battery runtimes are sold in amp hours AT THE RATED VOLTAGE FOR THE BATTERY - so you will need to multiply the AH by the voltage of the battery to get the the watt hours - which is more useful.  Most UPS manuals will have runtimes at various loads documented.

To calculate the amount of watts the battery can supply over time: Ah x V[olts] / H[ours] = W[atts] [Ah*V/H=W] e.g. 7Ah*12V/0.25H = 336W (a constant 336W can be supplied for 15min)

@JW0914  Your maths is right so it gives a first order approximation- although this ignores that voltage decreases as the battery is used, conversion losses, and the discharge cutoff.
